# Video doesn't play on live website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, html5-video, dotnetnuke

i have made a video module in which the user upload a video and video playback in a video tag

```
 <video id="Video1" runat="server" controls="controls" autoplay tabindex="5" visible="false"
                    class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{}">
                    <source id="Source1" runat="server" type="video/mp4" />
                    <source id="Source2" runat="server" type="video/flv" />
                </video>
```

.cs

```
public void getExtension(string Filename)
        {
            string Extension = "";
            Extension = Path.GetExtension(Filename);

            if (Extension == ".mp4")
            {
                Source1.Attributes.Add("src", Finalpath);
            }
            else if (Extension == ".flv")
            {
                Source2.Attributes.Add("src", Finalpath);
            }

        }
```

the particular module works at local but as i install this on Live website the Video doesn't play. i have inspected the page the url of video as follows at local

```
http://dc620x_dev2/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/erf/uyn/2.mp4
```

and 
at live

```
http://videoclasses.webhostcentric.com/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/Abc/yeghbf/2.mp4
```

it shows an error :

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

what i am missing or error in code. thanks for any assistence.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is present at that location? If yes, then there seems to be an issue with permission accessing that file/folder.

Comment: Sir file exist and permission is all set.

Comment: Is your webserver serving .mp4 files? Can you view a mp4 file that is on your website in a webbrowser?

Comment: Sir i can view the mp4 file on local. moreover the mp4 file works on all browser but on local. problem comes when i am trying to implement on it live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [mp4](http://videoclasses.webhostcentric.com/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/Abc/yeghbf/2.mp4) file is returning a 404 / file not found error. Either 1) the file is not located at that address or 2) your IIS webserver does not have the proper MIME type listed for mp4 files.

If you know the file exists at that location, check out this [Microsoft Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965) about IIS configuration:

> When you request a file from an IIS 6.0 Web server, and the file has a
>   file name extension that is not a defined MIME type on the Web server,
>   you receive the following error message: HTTP Error 404 - File or
>   directory not found.

You are using IIS 7.5, but the concept is the same. IS the MIME type set up correctly on your server?

Comment: sir, the module works on the local. the problem is coming on live site. i have checked the address the file exists at that position but when i am running the module it shows that The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: i was missing the MIME type on server. now it works thanks sir.